# How do you abbreviate the word "рубль" and its derived forms "рубля" and "рублей"?

Tags: сокращения

Let me express my own personal opinion. To my mind, words such as **рубль, рубля, рублей** must be abbreviated as **рубл.** Of course, I'll provide a link to the respective rule.

> При стечении двух одинаковых согласных сокращение следует делать после
> первой согласной, например: стен. календарь, грам. ошибка (а не
> стенн., грамм.). **При стечении двух различных** или нескольких **согласных**
> сокращение следует делать после последней согласной, например: народн.
> творчество (а не народ.), русск. язык (а не рус.), искусств. шёлк (а
> не искус., или искусс., или искусст.).

[hyperlink (therules.ru/abbreviations)](https://therules.ru/abbreviations/) — please read the last paragraph of section 116.

So, am I right? If somehow I'm not, then why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to abbreviate the word "рубль" and its forms "рубля", "рублей"?

Many authors have done exactly what you propose (used *рубл.*), and some probably still do.

The word *рубль*, however, has two syllables, with a schwa between *б* and *л*, which is not marked in writing. The "consonant confluence" the guide is talking about happens in writing, but not in speech.

Popov, *Фонетика современного русского языка, СПб. 2014*, p. 126:

> …в тех случаях, когда сонант оказывается в положении между
> двумя и более согласными (например, в таких словах, как *джентльмен*,
> *декабрьский* и под.) или после согласного на конце слова (*рубль, театр, монстр, тигр, вихрь* и т. п.), а гласный в соседстве с ним этимологически не предполагается, перед таким сонантом может появляться так называемый эпентетический (т. е. вставной) гласный: [džɨ-nt<sup>ɨ</sup>-l<sup>j</sup>'m<sup>j</sup>en] *джентльмен*, [ʌ-l<sup>j</sup>i-'ksɑ-nd<sup>ə</sup>r] *Александр*, ['ru-b<sup>ə</sup>l<sup>j</sup>] *рубль*, [ʌ-'kt<sup>j</sup>ɑ-b<sup>ə</sup>r<sup>j</sup>], *октябрь*, ['mo-nst<sup>ə</sup>r] *монстр*, ['t<sup>j</sup>i-g<sup>ə</sup>r] *тигр*, ['v<sup>j</sup>ix<sup>ə</sup>r<sup>j</sup>] *вихрь*.
>
> …
>
> Количество слогов в словоформе хорошо отражается в стихотворной речи. Ср. также трёхсложное [kʌ-'rɑ-b<sup>ə</sup>l<sup>j</sup>] в первом стихе и двухсложное [kʌ-'rɑbl<sup>j</sup>] во втором стихе произнесение слова *корабль* в детской скороговорке (четырехстопный хорей):
>
> Вёз корабль карамель,
> Налетел корабль на мель.
> И матросы три недели
> Карамель на мели ели.
>
> …
>
> Иногда вставка гласного отражается в литературных текстах как
> средство приближения к разговорной речи. Ср. написания *бод**о**р,
> Александ**е**р, теат**о**р* у А. К. Толстого, для которого вообще характерна передача на письме вставных гласных перед конечными сонантами.

More specialized guides recommend abbreviating *рубль* either as *руб.* or, better yet, as *р.*

Milchin et al., [*Справочник издателя и автора*, 4.4.6](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html#id-4%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-446%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7):

> Употреблять сокращения *руб.* и *коп.* взамен *р.* и *к.* допустимо лишь в изданиях для малоподготовленного читателя. В любом случае в пределах одного издания должна употребляться только одна форма сокращения — либо однобуквенная, либо трехбуквенная.

Comment: 'рубль, however, has two syllables' -- is that claim based on some grammar book? I failed to find a rule that "бль" constitutes a syllable... Quite to the contrary: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=242116

Comment: @IgorG: _тигр, рубль, корабль_ and other words with a schwa can lose the schwa when merged with clitics and other words with phonetical dependence, and also in poems for metrics purposes. As standalone words, _тигр_ and _рубль_ have two syllables, _корабль_ has three. The answer you're quoting is just wrong (it's not an uncommon thing with this particular service, back in the day I used to know some of its editors in person and have sent them numerous emails calling out the mistakes). Are you familiar with Sasha Chorny's poem _Обстановочка_? Try scanning its second line.

Comment: 'The answer you're quoting is just wrong' -- so, is there any reference to prove that? Has any linguist addressed that mistake? I'm insisting because that belief seems to be _extremely_ common. Even school textbooks (Litvinova) and orthoepic dictionaries (Avanesov) teach us that there's only one syllable in тигр and рубль. Poetry can hardly prove anything, as it's not uncommon for poets to bend words to their needs...

Comment: @IgorG: I'm far away from my books at the moment, will try to find a quote once I'm back.

Comment: @IgorG: see the update

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось найти только один правильный вариант - "руб."
Источник: https://ufabist.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/vkr-sokrascheniya.pdf

Почему "руб", а не "рубл"?
Потому что язык сломаешь, такие аббревиатуры произносить, да и к тому же это не эстетично